# Floquet exponents of the Meissner equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, periodic-functions

I am stuck on an attempted calculation in which I aim to find the Floquet Exponents of the Meissner equation (ie the Hill equation where the parametric driving is a square wave).

$\ddot{y} + (1 + r f(t) ) y = 0$

where $f(t) = 1$ for $0<t\leq T/2$, and $f(t) = -1$ for $T/2<t \leq T$.

Furthermore $f(t+T)=f(t)$.

Since the pieces are exactly solvable we write
$$
\dot Y =
\frac{d}{dt} 
\begin{pmatrix}
\dot y \\ y 
\end{pmatrix}
= 
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & -(1+r) \\
1 & r
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
\dot y \\ y 
\end{pmatrix}
 = M_+ Y
$$
for $0<t\leq T/2$. And
$$
\dot Y = 
\frac{d}{dt} 
\begin{pmatrix}
\dot y \\ y 
\end{pmatrix}
= 
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & -(1-r) \\
1 & r
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
\dot y \\ y 
\end{pmatrix}
 = M_- Y
$$
for $T/2<t\leq T$. The result is that
$$
Y(T) = e^{T M_-/2} e^{T M_+/2} Y(0) = B Y(0)
$$
I believe the Floquet multipliers are then the solutions to the characteristic equation

$$
|B - \rho I | = 0
$$

This equation is found to be

$$
\rho^2 - 2 \rho\left(\cos(\sqrt{1-r} \,T/2 ) \cos(\sqrt{1+r} \,T/2) -\frac{\sin(\sqrt{1-r}\, T/2) \sin(\sqrt{1+r}\, T/2)}{\sqrt{1-r^2}} \right) + 1 = 0
$$

I cannot see a way to massage this into the very simple form given on the  [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meissner_equation), which states that the floquet exponents for $T=2$ are the roots of the equation
$$
\lambda^2 - 2 \lambda \cos \sqrt{r} \cosh \sqrt{r} + 1 = 0
$$
Any pointers will be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure your solution of the characteristic equation is correct? Because I see that B is expressed with exponentials of $M_{-}$ and $M_{+}$ or so, given their look I would expext some exp() terms to pop up at some point. I've pushed the calculus to the exponentials of the two above matrices and there's a exp(r) in both of them; i would not expect it to disapear at the end, but maybe i'm wrong..

Comment: The exponentials lead to the $\sin$ and $\cos$. The piecewise solutions are both oscilliatory so with frequencies $\omega = \sqrt{1 \pm r}$ so I think one would expect it to be a function of $\sin(\sqrt{1 \pm r} T/2)$ and $\cos(\sqrt{1 \pm r} T/2)$. More specifically $\exp \frac{T}{2} \begin{pmatrix} 0 & -\omega^2 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} \cos(\omega t/2) & - \omega \sin(\omega t/2) \\ \sin(\omega t/2)/\omega & \cos(\omega t/2) \end{pmatrix}$.  Personally I cannot see how $e^{r}$ would appear.

Comment: I must do the complete calculus then, i'll tell you what i get

Comment: Excellent - let me know what you find.